# Printing out the number of characters in a string using a for each loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, printing, count, character

I'm supposed to create a program that prints out the number of characters in a string using a for each-loop. I have come up with this (yes, I am a beginner), and unfortunately it gives me a list of numbers. I'd prefer to have only the last number printed. If anyone out there is patient enough to give me a hint, I'd be eternally grateful. Please help a poor law student out!

```
string = input("Please put in a string of letters: ")

num = 0
for char in string:
    num = num + 1     
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, take the last line out of loop, like this...

```
string = input("Please put in a string of letters: ")
num = 0
for char in string:
    num = num + 1     
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if that is what you were looking for but if you take the `print(num)` statement out of the loop it will only print the final number.

```
string = input("Please put in a string of letters: ")

num = 0
for char in string:
    num = num + 1     
print(num)
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. If not please specify your problem so i can take another go at helping you out. If it helps but you dont understand why it works let me know and i will try to explain it to you.